# C# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. App hosted in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am facing this strange issue in production. While making remote https request to APIM, following error is thrown:

```
The SSL connection could not be established,  see inner exception.
Inner exception: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

{"assembly":"System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame","level":0,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback","level":1,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":2,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional","level":3,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication","level":4,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication","level":5,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient","level":6,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Security.SslStream+<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1","level":7,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic","level":8,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":9,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":10,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":11,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":12,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore>d__4.MoveNext","level":13,"line":0}
```

I have set security protocol to tls1.2 in the code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

When I hit https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check from production, I get following response:

```
{
  "given_cipher_suites": [
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
  ],
  "ephemeral_keys_supported": true,
  "session_ticket_supported": true,
  "tls_compression_supported": false,
  "unknown_cipher_suite_supported": false,
  "beast_vuln": false,
  "able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting": false,
  "insecure_cipher_suites": {
    "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA": [ "uses 3DES which is vulnerable to the Sweet32 attack but was not configured as a fallback in the ciphersuite order" ],
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA": [ "uses 3DES which is vulnerable to the Sweet32 attack but was not configured as a fallback in the ciphersuite order" ]
  },
  "tls_version": "TLS 1.2",
  "rating": "Bad"
}
```

Same function works correctly in DEV and QA environment. All environments are created using same pipeline (arm templates and code)

Comment: Which .NET runtime and *version* are you using? All relatively fresh version in .NET Framework use TLS1.2 automatically. In .NET Framework, the only versions that don't [are going out of support in 7 months](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/). If you use an obsolete version of .NET Framework you'll have to migrate.

Comment: `I have set security protocol to tls1.2 in the code:` why? Only unsupported or soon-to-be-unsupported versions require this. Hard-coding the protocol can *cause* problems instead of solving them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using dotnet core 3.1.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos since it is working in dev and qa env, this must be related to the infrastructure / network of prod, do you reckon what should I check next? one more thing calling APIM from local machine (VPN connected) also works. Can this be issue with firewall between azure function and APIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of the problem was the wrong IP Address configured in private DNS zone. We had two private DNS zone to resolve custom domain name of APIM, one was pointing to QA's APIM and other one pointing to PROD's APIM. We shouldn't have two private DNS zone in the first place and having wrong IP address was terrible mistake :(. Lesson learnt